# TYPO3 make a 2 level menu

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to make a menu like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="...">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">Item 2</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="...">Item 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="...">Subitem 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="...">Subitem 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

but instead I get this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="...">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">Item 3</a></li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="...">Subitem 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="...">Subitem 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

What should I change? This is my code:

```
10 = HMENU
10{
  special = directory
  special.value = 1

  1 = TMENU
  1{
    NO = 1
    NO{
      allWrap = <li>|</li>
    }
  }

  2 = TMENU
  2{
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>
    NO = 1
    NO.linkWrap = <li>|</li>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any magick, common `wrapItemAndSub` does the trick

```
lib.subMenu = HMENU
lib.submenu {
   1 = TMENU
   1 {
      wrap = <ul>|</ul>
      NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
   }

   2 < .1
   2.wrap = <ul class="level_2">|</ul>
}
```

of course you don't need to use separate class for each level, that's a bonus.